# Как удалить черные углы из функции warpPerspective из модуля CV2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, background, cv2

Я хочу чтобы черный фон заменился видео рядом. Снизу предоставлен код и пример кадра из видео

```
import cv2

# Create an object to read
# from camera
import numpy as np

video = cv2.VideoCapture('happy_new_year.mp4')


if (video.isOpened() == False):
    print("Error reading video file")
frame_width = int(video.get(3))
frame_height = int(video.get(4))

size = (frame_width, frame_height)

result = cv2.VideoWriter('filename.mp4',
                         cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V'),
                         30, size)
img = cv2.imread('family.jpg')
# img = cv2.imread('crocodile.png')
# Get Image dimensions
img_height, img_width, _ = img.shape
x = 50
y = 50

M = np.float32([[1, 0.5, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
sheared_img = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (int(img_width*1.5), int(img_height*1.5)))
img = sheared_img
img_height, img_width, _ = sheared_img.shape

while (True):
    ret, frame = video.read()
    frame[y:y + img_height, x:x + img_width] = img

    if ret == True:

        result.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
            break

    # Break the loop
    else:
        break

# When everything done, release
# the video capture and video
# write objects
video.release()
result.release()

# Closes all the frames
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print("The video was successfully saved")
```

[image: black background warpPerspective function from CV2 module]